# Не удается подписать и сохранить приложение

Tags: java, android

Пользуюсь ECLIPSE.
Создал новый Android проект HELLO World. - Кликаю правой кнопкой мыши по проекту: **Android tools > Export Unsigned Application Package** и тут появляется сообщение: `Export aborted because fatal lint errors ware found. These are listed in the Lint View. Either fix these before running Export again , or turn off "Run full error check when export app" in the Android > Lint Error Checking pereferance page.`[image: Это собственно ошибки]

не могу понять в чем дело. Так как я не чего в проектах не трогал, вообще. Просто создал его и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо или пофиксить эти линт ошибки или разрешить линт игнор. Эти настройки можно поменять следующим образом:
"Window" -> "Preferences" -> "Android" -> "Lint Error Checking"
(На маке, "Eclipse" -> "Preferences" -> "Android" -> "Lint Error Checking"). Eclipse среда разработки больше не является рекомендованной, т.к. есть официальный IDE - [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) Если Вы только начинаете разбработку на андроиде, советую использовать Android Studio